# Upgrading Xcode using App Store download problem

Tags: install, xcode, mac-appstore

I have Xcode 4.2 installed, but I need Xcode 4.3 so I can test an app on my iOS 5.1 device. However I have run into problems attempting to download the latest version from the Mac App Store.

Initially when I went to the store I noticed in the 'Purchases' tab Xcode was there, but back from when it was 4.2, so I removed it from purchases and then went to the Xcode page and clicked on the 'Install App'.

It certainly doesn't appear to be doing anything though, and the 'Purchases' tab now looks like this (clicking on the blank button does nothing):

[image]

I only use my Mac for iOS development, so know very little about installing/unistalling s/w on OS X. I.e. I'm hoping there's is something very simple and obvious I've missed (and i've been trying to sort this out for an annoyingly long amount of time now!)

Due to my failure with the App Store I'm currently downloading a version of Xcode 4.3.2 via a torrent - but this is a quite a dodgy route and I'd rather sort it out properly!

Comment: Is your Xcode in the applications folder?

Comment: @Stephen No it's not.

Comment: Could you tell me where it is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem but look and see if you have any hidden purchases on your account. The way to check is:

1. Launch the app store & Select Store > View My Account and sign in.
2. Look for a section headed iTunes in the Cloud, with a Hidden Purchases entry, and click View Hidden Purchases.
3. Click Unhide for those purchases you wish to appear in your App Store Purchases window, then click Done.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I found it there straight away and have sorted out the mess it got itself into :)